# matlab structure with two 1D arrays and one variable

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, data-structures

I want to create a structure in Matlab consisting in two 1-D arrays and one variable. So, I'm doing this:

```
IQinfo.I=inputI;
IQinfo.Q=inputQ;
IQinfo.fc=45e6;
```

However, my structure's size is 1, and I need to have a 1x3 structure. I've never used structures in Matlab before, so any help will be very welcomed! :)

Thanks!

Comment: `IQinfo` is 1x1, but has 3 fields. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Because Im saving the structure in a .mat file and its read from a program that uses a loop: index from 1 to length (structure) and it checks if s(index)=I, and I dont get that! :(

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the program that is using this struct to your question?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing the size of the struct, and the number of fields it has. If you create a struct like this

```
>> iqinfo.I = [1, 2, 3];
>> iqinfo.Q = [4, 5, 6];
>> iqinfo.fc = 45e6;
```

Then its size is 1x1

```
>> size(iqinfo)
ans =
     1     1
```

But it has 3 fields

```
>> size(fieldnames(iqinfo))
ans =
     3     1
```

which are the ones you assigned

```
>> fieldnames(iqinfo)
ans = 
    'I'
    'Q'
    'fc'
```

If you wanted to create a struct array (an array of structs) then you could do this

```
>> iqinfo(2) = struct('I', [1 2 3], 'Q', [4 5 6], 'fc', 90e6);
>> iqinfo(3) = struct('I', [4 5 6], 'Q', [7 8 9], 'fc', 100e6);
>> size(iqinfo)
ans =
     1     3
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I want. Because I just one vector Q and one vector I, but in the function it checks this: s(k).name('I'), s(k).name('Q') and s(k).name('fc') for k=1:length(s)

Comment: Actually, the instructions of the program that does that say: "IQinfo has to be of the following form: IQinfo.I_data=1D array of I-data, IQinfo.Qdata=1D array of Q-data and IQinfo.clock=desire clock rate"

Comment: and also it says: "the program expect a '.mat' file contanining a 1D I-data and a 1D Q-data array named I and Q respectively. Additionally, the '.mat' file must contain the clock frequency as a variable named fc"

Comment: @NataliaMolineroMingorance It looks like you are trying to save structure fields as separate variables. So, maybe this would work for you - `save('saved_data.mat', '-struct', 'IQinfo')`. More info - http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/import_export/save-structure-fields-as-separate-variables.html

Comment: @Divakar yaaay! thanks!! it's that what I need!! thank you!! :D